# Query for retrieving random records from MS Access

Tags: ms-access, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get random record from MS Access database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937222/how-to-get-random-record-from-ms-access-database)

In my project I have gone through a scenario, where i have to retrieve records from MS Access table RANDOMLY. What query should I use to retrieve the records in a random base??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that in a table `MyTable` you have a primary key `ID` field in a that is an autoincrement integer, you can do something like this to retrieve, say 10 random records from `MyTable`:

```
SELECT Top 10 *
FROM   (SELECT *,
           Rnd(ID) AS RandomValue
        FROM   MyTable)
ORDER  BY RandomValue
```

**Edit:**
Found another similar answer: [How to get random record from MS Access database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937222)