# How to get random record from MS Access database

Tags: ms-access, random

I have a MS access database.
In that, one table consists of questions and answers with primary key questionID.
I need to retrieve random question from that table using questionID.
What keywords or query should I use for this scenario.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following will get a random questionID from your table

MySQL

```
SELECT questionID FROM questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

MS Access

```
SELECT top 1 questionID from questions ORDER BY rnd(questionID)
```

Comment: the version for MS Access, does seem to generate random records - but the same ones each time!

Comment: AGREE.. same random records

Answer (score 26):

To get different random record you can use, which would require a ID field in your table

```
SELECT TOP 1 questionID FROM questions ORDER BY Rnd(-(100000*questionID)*Time())
```

A negative value passed as parameter to the Rnd-function will deliver the first random value from the generator using this parameter as start value. (A kind of defined randomize).
Special thanks to @kobik 's hint from the comments.

Comment: Funny thing. I have tested all suggested answers including this I get different/random records. but as soon as I run my test program again the results are in the same sequence as before. as if the random seed generator resets each time in ms-access. I later found this:
[Random Number Generator Query Not So Random](http://database.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/access-l/random-number-generator-query-not-so-random-3887838)

Comment: it does same thing bummi,  each time i run it i get the same 4 results

Comment: so how you suggest to fix @Kobik

Comment: @GlenMorse, There is a working workaround (Bummi, you might wan to edit your answer): [ORDER BY NEWID() in MS Access](http://oxle.com/topic.asp?archive=true&tid=3514). so using a negative number with `Rnd()` "fixes" the problem. use: `ORDER BY Rnd(-(1000*ID)*Time())`

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT TOP 5 questionID FROM [tableName] ORDER BY rnd(INT(NOW*questionID)-NOW*questionID)
```

This will give you a new set of answers every time, you don't even need to make up a time when you use "NOW" (which will every time be a new time you click this no matter how fast you click), in my opinion the most simple and neat way to solve this in Access.

Comment: This one works perfectly okay for me. All other methods gives the same set of records. Good work.