# How to correctly use syntax for RAND()

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access, delphi-xe2

keep getting error when it try to select 4 random rows. not sure i got the snytax right for doing this.  Also note i am using an access db. Also note.. ManaTypes is an array of strings.

```
with adoquery1 do
begin
  close;
  sql.Clear;
  sql.Add('SELECT * ');
  sql.Add('FROM Cards ');
  sql.Add('WHERE Color='+ManaTypes[i]+' ORDER BY RAND() Limit 4');
  open;
end;
```

Getting error 'snytax error (missing operator ) in query expression 'Color="

Comment: Also try `ORDER BY Rnd`

Comment: yes of course :D   also ORDER BY Rnd Limit 4 did not work either same error

Comment: Did you add a space after `cards` as well?

Comment: yes added that as well

Comment: That question was asked over a year ago and does not supply answer.. how did you even find it lol..

Comment: Hi Glen, I added an answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937222/how-to-get-random-record-from-ms-access-database

Comment: @Bummi That does same thing as these...same results.

Comment: I really hope it dont get closed, as the DUPE question has wrong answer..

Comment: Proper way would be deleting this question and adding a bounty to that duplicate. I would set a bounty there, but I don't have time to test the answers since I don't have time nor Access (to be more precise even don't want to have Access).

Comment: its been updated there... i just hope someone changes the answer to the correct answer...in which case i dont care if htis is now deleted

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
sql.Add(
   'SELECT Top 4 *
    FROM
    (
       SELECT *, Rnd(ID) AS RandomValue
       FROM Cards 
       WHERE Color = "' + ManaTypes[i] + '"
    )
    ORDER  BY RandomValue'
```

Comment: That worked or at least ran.. but had to swap the ' and "  around

Comment: also it seems to give the same 4 random ones each time?

Comment: Still works, but still same 4 random ones.. does random not work like i think it should?