# Getting a single random value from a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

How do i retrieve a single record from a data base but in a random manner? Any help you put forward will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

This is what i have done so far

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Ahmed'susopriore'\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication11\WebApplication11\Questions.accdb";
    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
    Random rnd = new Random();
    rnd.Next();
    string myQuery = "SELECT * FROM Questions ORDER BY rnd()";
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, connection);
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
        ListBox1.Items.Add(reader["Number"]+"" );
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label1.Text = "ERROR!"+ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580639/how-to-randomly-select-rows-in-sql

Comment: What's the problem with your existing code? Do you get an error, or does it not give the expected results? What is it doing that you don't want it to do?

Comment: The existing code that i have now displays all the items in the column and does it in reverse order instead of doing it randomly

Comment: Just because it comes back in an order you recognize doesnt mean its not random.  If you dont specify an order by clause, you have no guarantee of the order from a sql database.

Comment: there are no errors. My aim is to get a single random item from the database instead of a whole column.

Comment: how do i specify by clause?

Comment: If you want something that seems truly random, pull the table into your own list of objects with a new guid as one of the properties of your new object.  Then order by the guid

Comment: Ok, how do i achieve in getting a single value from a database?

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Questions ORDER BY rnd()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If primary key of questions is `questionId`
Change your code from:

```
string myQuery = "SELECT * FROM Questions ORDER BY rnd()";
```

to:

```
string myQuery = "SELECT Top 1 * FROM Questions ORDER BY rnd(questionID)";
```

Or:

```
string myQuery = "SELECT Top 1 * FROM Questions ORDER BY Rnd(-(100000*questionID)*Time())
```

Comment: nearly there...it does it in a reverse order instead of a random one and display all items in that column

Comment: i did not follow you. what you mean with "`display all items in that column`"

Comment: iv got a column called "Number" in my database and its from 1-4. Using a while loop i added the numbers to a ListBox1.Items.Add(reader["Number"]+"" );  once i run the programme and click the button they come out as 4321

Comment: it says ERROR!System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): Undefined function 'NEWID' in expression. How do i define "NEWID"?

Comment: sorry i thought you use Sql server. I change code for using Ms Access Database.

Comment: Much appreciated brother, what you did worked but it only shows the 4th question only as are 4 questions. How do i get it to display a random question every time i click the button?

Comment: Your welcome. take look at this: change `rnd(questionId)` with `Rnd(-(100000*questionID)*Time())`.

Comment: AFAIK, the only way to get random is to get it from db. Also look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937222/how-to-get-random-record-from-ms-access-database

Comment: It worked! Seyed your a legend!! i cant thank you enough god bless you brother!