# to labels put random values from database c#

Tags: c#, ms-access, label

I need to select from database random nicknames and show these nicknames to multiple labels.

My code show only one nickname in all these labels ,but I need after button click random nicknames ,what is in database ,show in labels.

```
void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=names.mdb";
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT ID,nickname FROM names where ID=3 ";
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read()){
                label1.Text=reader["nickname"].ToString();
                label2.Text=reader["nickname"].ToString();
                label3.Text=reader["nickname"].ToString();
                label4.Text=reader["nickname"].ToString();
                label5.Text=reader["nickname"].ToString();
                label6.Text=reader["nickname"].ToString();
                label7.Text=reader["nickname"].ToString();
                label8.Text=reader["nickname"].ToString();
            }
            connection.Close(); 
        }
```

example of form
http://greenlight.ucoz.lv/11cqsvX/ac_lb.png

to label1 nickname1,
to label2 nickname26,
to label3 nickname78,
...

Please help me and sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: In the while loop you populate every label with the same text.
Anyway, if ID is a unique index you'll get only 1 nickname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get answer ,now my code look this

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=names.mdb";
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT ID,nickname FROM names ORDER BY rnd(ID)";
            foreach (Control control in Controls)
  {
    if (control is Label)
    {
      OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
      reader.Read();
      control.Text = reader["nickname"].ToString();
      reader.Close();
    }
  }
            connection.Close();
```

Thanks @MikeB

Comment: Don't close the reader, put it in a [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) instead. You should do the same with the connection and command too.

Comment: @eatmailyo Welcome to SO!  Instead of writing up your own answer you should upvote & accept MikeB's answer since it's pretty much identical to what you just posted.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain without closing reader ,my programm doesnt work :(

Comment: To accept an answer, click the green check mark to its upper left. You don't have to upvote it.

Comment: Using a `using` statments calls `.Dispose()` for you, `Dispose()` calls `Close()` for you. You are still closing the reader, you are just closing it the "correct" way by disposing of it.

Answer (score 1):

My idea would be to modify your SQL to [select a random row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql), since your current SQL will always select the same row. Do this for every label you have by iterating through each label.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
  connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=names.mdb";
  connection.Open();

  foreach (Control control in Controls)
  {
    if (control is Label)
    {
      OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
      command.Connection = connection;
      command.CommandText = "SELECT nickname FROM names ORDER BY rnd(ID)";
      OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
      reader.Read();
      control.Text = reader["nickname"].ToString();
    }
  }
  connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: can you please show me how to make this in my code? because im beginner in c# and dont know how to

Comment: i dont know why ,but to me have error - Undefined function 'NEWID' in expression.

Comment: oops. I didn't see you were using MS Access. The SQL has been modified per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937222/how-to-get-random-record-from-ms-access-database

Comment: i read about this, but i cant understand how to write this in my code :( can you please help?

Comment: I write like this `ORDER BY rnd(ID)` and then I get error "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `OlDbConnection`, but it seems that each command should be read and then closed. I've updated the code in my answer

Comment: @MikeB your error is you should be putting the readers in `using` statements so they get disposed. (you should do the same for the command and connection too)