# Access Query - how to randomly select records

Tags: ms-access, select, random

I have this query that creates a list of 10 names that are in my facebookfriends list that are not already in my contact list, but I want it to randomly select these 10 names.

I can't get the other examples to work with my query, please can you help me get this right.

Here is the sql:

```
SELECT TOP 10 FaceBookFriends.FaceBookName, FaceBookFriends.FullName,
              FaceBookFriends.FirstName, FaceBookFriends.Surname, 
              FaceBookFriends.DateAdded
FROM FaceBookFriends LEFT JOIN Contact_List
  ON FaceBookFriends.[FullName] = Contact_List.[Full _Name]
WHERE (((Contact_List.[Full _Name]) Is Null));
```

I added a `ORDER BY Rnd(FaceBookFriends.FullName)` at the end of the report but it doesn't work.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to get random record from MS Access database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937222/how-to-get-random-record-from-ms-access-database)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get random record from MS Access database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937222/how-to-get-random-record-from-ms-access-database)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in order by clause:

```
order by newid()
```