# Microsoft Access query to retrieve random transactions with seemingly impossible criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access, random, ms-access-2010

I was asked to assist with developing a report to retrieve a 25% sample of random transactions within a specific date range. I am not a programmer but I was able to devise the following fairly quickly:

```
SELECT TOP 25 PERCENT account.CID, account.ACCT, account.NAME, log.DATE, log.action_txt, log.field_nm, log.from_data, log.to_data, log.tran_id, log.init 
FROM account INNER JOIN log ON account.ACCT = log.ACCT
GROUP BY account.CID, account.ACCT, account.NAME, log.DATE, log.action_txt, log.field_nm, log.from_data, log.to_data, log.tran_id, log.init
HAVING (((log.DATE) Between #2/7/2018# And #6/15/2018#) AND ((log.action_txt)="mod" Or (log.action_txt)="del") AND ((log.init)="J1X" 
ORDER BY log.tran_dt
```

This returns 25% of the records within the date range. Each record row is unique but each account number potentially has multiple records on each day. In some cases the records have the same date and tran_id as well.

Upon further discussion with the requester, he actually wants to see all of the transactions for **25% of the accounts that have activity on each day within the date range**. Thus if there were 100 accounts on 3/1/2018 with records in this table, he wants to see all of the transactions for 25 of those accounts; if there were 60 accounts on 3/2/2018 with records in this table, he wants to see all of the transactions for 15 of those accounts; and so on.

I was thinking that an Access module would work best in this scenario as I believe there are multiple parts to this. I figured that I need a function to loop through the date range and for each day:
1. Count the account numbers only one time
2. Return all of the transactions for 25% of the total accounts

But as I mentioned, I am not a programmer and I am exhausted from searching possible solutions for the many parts.

Comment: [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271). Sample data and expected result is much more useful than a textual description.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key to your question is that you only really need a pseudo random selection of results for your report. So you can force the Random number generator to reorder your results based on a value in the record and the current time.

Something like this should work - I assume your actiontxt field is a text field and pull out the length of each field and apply that to current date/time to create a pseudo random number that can be sorted.

All I really do is change your `ORDER BY` line

See if this works for you

```
SELECT TOP 25 PERCENT 
account.CID, account.ACCT, account.NAME, log.DATE, log.action_txt, log.field_nm, log.from_data, 
log.to_data, log.tran_id, log.init 
FROM account 
INNER JOIN log ON account.ACCT = log.ACCT
GROUP BY account.CID, account.ACCT, account.NAME, log.DATE, log.action_txt, log.field_nm, log.from_data, log.to_data, log.tran_id, log.init
HAVING (((log.DATE) Between #2/7/2018# And #6/15/2018#) AND ((log.action_txt)="mod" Or (log.action_txt)="del") AND ((log.init)="J1X" 
ORDER BY Rnd(CLng(Now()*Len(log.action_txt))-(Now()*Len(log.action_txt)));
```

Modified similar idea from [other StackOverflow question and response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43087070/2419128)