# MS Access - Rank on TEXT fields

Tags: ms-access, text, rank

In MS Access 2000, I have a table named [Stack Trace] from which I should randomly pull 400 records with distinct of one of the text columns. 
I looked at one of the examples in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937218/query-for-retrieving-random-records-from-ms-access) and added an autonumber field to the table and wrote the query as below:

Assume that [Appraisal Name] is the distinct field needed and ID is the autonumbered primary key, what should be the query to find random 400 records with one of the text fields having distinct values?

First query without Distinct [Appraisal Name].

```
SELECT Top 400 *
FROM   (SELECT *,
           Rnd(ID) AS RandomValue
        FROM  [Street Data])
ORDER  BY RandomValue ASC
```

I know I can easily achieve that in sql server with Rank operation. I do not see any helpful links to find rank on varchar/text fields. I tried to find rank using the below query. It did not work out.

```
SELECT
    ID,
    [Appraiser Name],
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM [Street Data] WHERE
        [Appraiser Name] <= T.[Appraiser Name]
    ) AS Rank
FROM [Street Data] AS T
ORDER BY ID, [Appraiser Name]
```

Any helps are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it some how. But I welcome if there are any easy ways to do it. I created three queries. First one to find the rank of the Appraiser Name, second one to find the distinct of Appraiser Name and third one is the final query. I tried to use the first one in the query with rank = 1 and it gave me **join not supported** error. That is bad. When I created another query with rank = 1 and then used it in the final one, it worked.

**StreetData_Appraiser**

```
SELECT ID, [Appraiser Name], (
        SELECT COUNT([Appraiser Name])
        FROM [Street Data]
WHERE [Appraiser Name] = T.[Appraiser Name]
AND ID <= T.ID
    ) AS Rank
FROM [Street Data] AS T
ORDER BY ID, [Appraiser Name]
```

**StreetData_Distinct_Appraiser** (Query to mask the first query and show only distinct records and to avoid invalid join error)

```
SELECT * FROM StreetData_Appraiser WHERE Rank = 1
```

**Final Query**

```
SELECT TOP 400 *
FROM (SELECT ST.*,
           Rnd(ST.ID) AS RandomValue
        FROM  [Street Data] AS ST
        INNER JOIN [StreetData_Distinct_Appraiser] AS SA ON SA.ID=ST.ID)  AS STRecs
ORDER BY RandomValue
```