# Random query returns same records each time

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9937425/159072

I am using the following query to select 5 random records from a table,

```
SELECT Top 5 *
FROM   (SELECT *,
           Rnd(ID) AS RandomValue
        FROM   Words)
ORDER  BY RandomValue
```

This query works fine in MS Access.

But, the problem occurs when I use it in a c# application. It returns same 5 records on each occasion.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Text;

namespace MicrosiftAccessDbProviderFactory______Test
{
    public class MyClass 
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\db1.mdb;Persist Security Info=False";
            string providerName = @"System.Data.OleDb";
            DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName);

            IDbConnection Connection = factory.CreateConnection();
            Connection.ConnectionString = connString;
            Connection.Open();

            IDbTransaction Transaction = Connection.BeginTransaction();

            IDbCommand Command = factory.CreateCommand();
            Command.Connection = Connection;
            Command.Transaction = Transaction;

            int count = 5;

            Command.CommandText = @"SELECT Top " + count + @" ID, Name
                                    FROM   (SELECT *,
                                               Rnd(ID) AS RandomValue
                                            FROM   Words)
                                    ORDER  BY RandomValue";
            IDataReader dataReader = Command.ExecuteReader();
            IList<MyClass> list = null;
            MyClass item = null;
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                if (list == null)
                {
                    list = new List<MyClass>();
                }

                item = new MyClass();
                item.ID = dataReader.GetInt32(0);
                item.Name = dataReader.GetString(1);

                list.Add(item);
            }

            dataReader.Close();

            Transaction.Commit();

            string str = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

**How can I solve this issue?**

Comment: Looks like you are using two different tables (MyTable and Words).

Comment: @jdweng, that was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *salt* the Rnd function, like:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable ORDER BY Rnd(-Timer()*[ID])
```

Thus, in your query:

```
Command.CommandText = @"SELECT Top " + count + @" ID, [Name]
                        FROM Words
                        ORDER BY Rnd(-Timer()*[ID])";
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been intriguing me.  What actually fascinates me is why it works in Access.  I can understand why it doesn't work with c#: the rnd() is always initialised with the same values.  My solution is UGLY but it works.  What I am hoping is that someone will look at the solution and see how it can be improved.  At least it contains the seeds of an idea, how to make this work between Access and c#.

Step 1.

Create a table (WordsGUID) in Access identical to the target table, but with one extra field, RandomGUID, set as Data Type AutoNumber, Field Size Replication Id.  For good measure, I made it indexed no duplicates, but I doubt that that is necessary.

Step 2.

Insert the following in C#

```
Command.CommandText ="DELETE FROM WordsGUID";
Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Command.CommandText ="INSERT INTO WordsGUID SELECT * FROM Words";
Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Command.CommandText ="SELECT TOP 5 * FROM WordsGUID ORDER BY RandomGUID";
IDataReader dataReader = Command.ExecuteReader();
```

etc..

As I said ugly, and probably horribly slow if you have a large table, but I couldn't think of anything better!

Comment: You could do those 3 steps in oneL `SELECT top 5 * FROM Words order by newid()` (at least, this works in MS SQL; I've not used Access in years).

Comment: @JohnLBevan Unfortunately no NewId() in Access